# How to add textbox data to a database?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am making a school project and i need to put text input (name and gender) into a database. This database (the names and genders) then have to be shown in a listbox. The code i have at the moment is put below, how can i make it work? Thanks in advance!

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM 
   Persoon", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable PersoonTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(PersoonTable);
            lb_gebruikers.DisplayMember = "Naam";
            lb_gebruikers.ValueMember = "Id";
            lb_gebruikers.DataSource = PersoonTable;
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string naam = tb_naam.Text;
        string geslacht = tb_geslacht.Text;



        Persoon nieuwpersoon = new Persoon(naam, geslacht);
        personen.Add(nieuwpersoon);

        foreach (var Persoon in personen)
        {
            lb_gebruikers.Items.Add("Naam: " + nieuwpersoon.Naam + 
  "Geslacht: " + nieuwpersoon.Geslacht);

        }

    }
```

Comment: now let me understand clearly. Do you want add Person to database's Person Table with Name and Gender Value right ?

Comment: @KadirKalkan Yes, i have a database table named 'Persoon' (person), and i have 2 textboxes with a button. The first textbox is for the name ('naam'), the second one is for the gender ('geslacht'). Both of these values need to be added to the database, and then displayed in my listbox.

Comment: ok i got it i will give answer in 5 minutes with code.

Comment: @KadirKalkan okay, thank you!

Comment: one more thing do you using entity framework or simple sql server database connection

Comment: Oh sorry, I am deleting my answer, @KadirKalkan will answer you as you discussed.

Comment: @Aria doesn't matter dude :) you can give answer my question :) how can i earn right to ask question :D

Comment: @KadirKalkan just sql server database connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand you just have to add a insert between button1.click and addToList process.

```
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server =.;Database=People; Integrated Security = true");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); // you can define commandText and connection in SqlCommand(defineArea);
                cmd.Connection = con;              // like; cmd = newSqlCommand("Insert into...",con);
                string name = txtName.Text;
                string gender = txtGender.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Person(Name,Gender)values('" + name + "','" + gender + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();

                lstBxPerson.Items.Add(name + " - " + gender);
                MessageBox.Show("Save Success!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception : "+ex);
            }
        }
```

Database Name : People

Table Name : Person

All Parts Image : [image: Image Of Code,Database And Result]

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that this may be vulnerable to SQL injection. However, since it's for a school project it probably doesn't matter much. :)

Comment: The 'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery' is giving an error when i try to add a name and gender. the error is 'System.InvalidOperationException: for Executenonquery is an open connection needed. the status of the connection is closed. ' How do i fix this?

Comment: i fixed it. i think about mvc so i did a mistake while using connection. But i couldn't try if it wrong again i can prepare a simulation form project :D

Comment: @KadirKalkan cmd.ExecuteNonQuery now gives the error 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'Person'.'

Comment: Person is your database table's name. 
The insert command is creates from "Inser into Table_Name(Column1,Column2)Values(Column1'sValue,Colum2'sValue)"

Comment: Okay, now the problem lays at the foreach part when trying to add a name and gender: 'System.ArgumentException: 'can not change the collection when datasource is turned on.'

Comment: i am sorry i haven't got sql server so i installed it because of this i late

Comment: @KadirKalkan I will try it later, i dont have time at the moment. thank you very much helping!

Comment: you are welcome. If you can confirm my answer after try it this will help me alot because i have a serious question and a question ban :D

Comment: @KadirKalkan It works, thanks a lot! I confirmed the answer as correct.

Comment: @KadirKalkan I can add the data to listbox now, but when i refresh my database in visual studio nothing changes, any idea why?

Comment: Visual studio is a shell if you don't bind it with your database you can't see changes for each change, you have to pull them and show for your project.